# Ansible roles with tags and lots of parameters

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make my roles readable and at the same time enable tags for them

```
- { role: 'init' }

- role: common, tags: 'common'
  pA: "pA"
  pB: "pB"
  pC: "pC"
- role: special
  sA: "sA"
```

But the above is not allowed/gives an error. Any suggestions on how to define tags in my playbook for my roles and still have lots of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
- role: common
  tags: common
  pA: pA
  pB: pB
  pC: pC
```

or for increased readability:

```
- role: common
  tags: common
  vars:
    pA: pA
    pB: pB
    pC: pC
```

<sup>All values are strings, so quotes are unnecessary.</sup>